React Application Not Redirecting to Login Page on Logout
I'm developing a React application with user authentication. I want to automatically redirect users to the login page when they log out (i.e., when their authentication token is removed). However, the application doesn't redirect until I manually refresh the page.
Here are the relevant parts of my code:
DefaultLayout.jsx:
import {React, useEffect} from "react";
import { Navigate, Outlet,useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useStateContext } from "../contexts/ContextProvider";
import axiosClient from "../axios-client.js";
import SideBar from "./nav/SideBar";
import Header from "./nav/Header";

const DefaultLayout = () => {
    const { user, token, isAuthenticated, setUser, setToken } = useStateContext();

    if (!token) {
        return <Navigate to="/login" />;
    }

    const onLogout = (ev) => {
        ev.preventDefault()

        axiosClient.post('/logout')
            .then(() => {
                window.location.reload()
                setUser({})
                setToken(null)
            })
    }

   
};

ContextProvider:
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

const StateContext = createContext({
    currentUser: null,
    token: null,
    notification: null,

    setUser: () => {},
    setToken: () => {},
    setNotification: () => {}
})

export const ContextProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({});
    const [token, _setToken] = useState(localStorage.getItem('ACCESS_TOKEN'));

    const [notification, _setNotification] = useState('');

    const setToken = (token, callback) => {
        _setToken(token)
        if (token) {
            localStorage.setItem('ACCESS_TOKEN', token);

        } else {
            localStorage.removeItem('ACCESS_TOKEN');
        }
    }

}

App.js:
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Sidebar from "./components/nav/SideBar.jsx";
import Header from "./components/nav/Header.jsx";
import Dashboard from "./views/Dashboard";
import GuestLayout from './components/GuestLayout.jsx'
import { useStateContext } from "./contexts/ContextProvider";
import Users from "./views/customers/Users.jsx";
import ListCustomers from "./views/customers/ListCustomers.jsx";
import {Outlet} from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {

    return (
        <Router>
            <div className="page-wrapper">
                <Sidebar />
                <div className="body-wrapper">
                    <Header />
                    <Routes>
                        <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />} />
                        <Route path="users" element={<Users />}>
                            <Route index element={<Outlet />}>
                                <Route path="list-customers" element={<ListCustomers />} />
                            </Route>
                        </Route>

                    </Routes>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
};

Logout button in Header component:
import React, {useEffect} from "react";

export default function Header({ user, onLogout }) {

    return (
        <header className="app-header">
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
                <ul className="navbar-nav">
                    <li className="nav-item d-block d-xl-none">
                        <a className="nav-link sidebartoggler nav-icon-hover" id="headerCollapse" href="javascript:void(0)">
                            <i className="ti ti-menu-2"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <a className="nav-link nav-icon-hover" href="javascript:void(0)">
                            <i className="ti ti-bell-ringing"></i>
                            <div className="notification bg-primary rounded-circle"></div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                {user.name} &nbsp; &nbsp;
                <button onClick={onLogout} className="btn btn-primary">Logout</button>
                
            </nav>
        </header>
    );
}

I've tried several solutions, including using a callback with setToken and moving the navigation logic into the setToken function in my ContextProvider, and adding a condition in my App.js file to render the DefaultLayout component only when the user is authenticated. However, these solutions either didn't work or resulted in an infinite loop of refreshes.
I'm a beginner and I'm building this project by following a YouTube tutorial. I'm not sure why the same code works in other applications but not in mine. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
I attempted to solve the issue by suggesting different approaches. I expected that one of these solutions would resolve the problem and the application would automatically redirect to the login page when the authentication token is removed. However, despite trying several solutions, the issue persisted. The application did not redirect to the login page immediately upon logout and instead required a manual page refresh. In some cases, the suggested solutions resulted in an infinite loop of refreshes. This was not the expected outcome, and I'm currently looking for alternative solutions to this problem.

I suspect it's this window.location.reload() that interrupts clearing the token out of localStorage so when the page is reloaded whatever value was previously stored there remains. I suspect you've then also some additional logic elsewhere the validates the token when the app mounts because of the reload which then works because the token is invalidated.
I suggest removing window.location.reload() so the app remains mounted, and move the redirect logic into the logout handler. I suggest also centralizing the auth logic into the context provider.
Example:
const StateContext = createContext({
  currentUser: null,
  token: null,
  notification: null,

  setUser: () => {},
  setToken: () => {},
  setNotification: () => {},
  logout: () => {},
})

export const ContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [token, setToken] = useState(() => {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('ACCESS_TOKEN'));
  });

  const [notification, _setNotification] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (token) {
      localStorage.setItem('ACCESS_TOKEN', JSON.stringify(token));
    } else {
      localStorage.removeItem('ACCESS_TOKEN');
    }
  }, [token]);

  const logoutHandler = () => {
    axiosClient.post('/logout')
      .then(() => {
        setUser(null);
        setToken(null);
      })
      .then(() => {
        navigate("/login", { replace: true });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // catch/handle any thrown errors or Promise rejections
      });
  };

  ...

  const value = {
    currentUser,
    token,
    notification,
    setUser,
    setToken,
    setNotification,
    logout,
  };

  return (
    <StateContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </StateContext>
  );
}

const DefaultLayout = () => {
  const {
    user,
    token,
    isAuthenticated,
    logout,
  } = useStateContext();

  const onLogout = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();

    logout();
  }

  ... 
};


This should work, but you don't need to chain .thens together. As you stated the root of the issue is that window.location.reload() is happening before the local storage is being cleared, could also just move it to after that happens.

@JoeLissner I'd agree with that "chaining" statement about 99% of the time... but because React state updates are processed asynchronously and navigation actions take effect immediately, moving the navigate to an additional .then provides the Javascript event queue to process the enqueued React state updates prior to the navigation being effected. This helps in situations where you are using the same state you are updating to protect routes so they are available when you attempt to navigate to them.
